# How to use RegEx to replace items based on their context, without affecting the context

Tags: ruby, regex

Using Ruby, I am writing a regular expression, and I need to be a able to remove any colon that appears between parentheses. I understand that I can use

```
"This is a (string :)".sub!(/\([^\)]*:/, '')
```

to do this, but the problem is that this function will also remove the context along with it. Is there any way to specify that I only want it to remove the colon and not the entire matching expression?

Comment: is it one colon, or many ? only (:), or (:s:a:d) ? Anywayz from my answer you can develop your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So some regular expression engines support what are called look-ahead and look-behind matches that will match but not consume characters. Ruby does support look-ahead, but not look-behind (which is more difficult to do in a performant way), which means you could quite easily stick with `sub` and remove a colon that precedes a closing parenthesis, but only without ensuring it is after an opening parenthesis:

```
string = 'This is a (string :)'
string.sub /:(?=\))/, ''
# => 'This is a (string )'
```

The alternative would be to use subpattern capturing (which happens automatically when you use grouping in your regular expression) to rebuild the string without the undesirable portion, in this case the colon:

```
string.sub /(\([^:]+):\)/, '\1)'
```

The `\1` is a back-reference to what is matched in the first group, which is delimited by the parentheses that are not escaped. You can see here I didn't bother capturing the closing parenthesis in a second group, opting instead simply to include it in the substitution. This works well in this case because it will not change, but if you don't know that the colon will appear at the end of the parentheses-enclosed content, you would need a second group:

```
string.sub /(\([^:]+):([^)]+\))/, '\1\2'
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I don't completely understand the first regular expression, but I'll be looking into what the ? does at the start of a group. Thanks for the help

Comment: Note that it isn't the question mark alone, but the pattern `(?=` which begins a look-ahead match, terminated by a closing parenthesis.

Comment: you proably want to also exclude `)` from your before-colon group to avoid deleting colons outside of parens eg: `([^:\)]+)`.  Your final `#sub` regexp would delete the colon in `'(foo) : (bar)'`. Caveats about regexp recognizing nested parens apply too.

Comment: all these solutions fail to remove multiple colons from within paren groups.  Try this sample string `'x (a:b:c) : (1:2:3) y'`

Comment: @dbenhur The thing with regular expressions is that they're only valid for regular data. I generally avoid coding for hypothetical future-cases, and I translate this to StackOverflow by trying to avoid interpreting needs as being the widest-possible (code-golf questions excepted). Often an answer that seems to fail to account for various edge cases can answer the question in a more targeted fashion. This, I feel, is one of those cases.

Comment: @dbenhur And I do hope that a member for 7 months wouldn't downvote an on-topic and good-intentioned answer that does actually address the question simply for a perceived failure to account for edge cases.

Comment: @coreyward OP:"I need to be a able to remove _any_ colon that appears between parentheses."  This answer doesn't miss just an "edge condition" it fails on a requirement -- it deletes colons outside of parens, and misses colons within parens.

Comment: Re: "The thing with regular expressions is that they're only valid for regular data"  Once you introduce back-references, you've already moved beyond the formal language theoretic definition of [regular grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13699/discussion-between-dbenhur-and-coreyward)

Comment: Good answer, I just want to mention that ruby does look-behind these days.

Answer (score 1):

The prior answer will mostly work for deleting single colons within paren groups, but have trouble with multiples like '(thing:foo:bar)`.  It would be nice to use lookbehind and lookahead to make the within parens assertion, but ruby (and most regexp engines) doesn't support non-deterministic length patterns in lookbehind.

```
irb> s = 'x (a:b:c) : (1:2:3) y'
=> "x (a:b:c) : (1:2:3) y"

irb> s.gsub /(?<=\([^\(]*):(?=[^\)]*\))/, ''
SyntaxError: (irb):10: invalid pattern in look-behind: /(?<=\([^\(]*):(?=[^\)]*\))/
    from /Users/dbenhur/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-wp/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

You could instead use the block form of gsub to capture paren enclosed groups, then remove colons from each match:

```
irb> s.gsub(/\([^\)]*\)/) {|m| m.delete ':'}
=> "x (abc) : (123) y"
```

Answer (score 0):

in regex in general, you can use `'(\()(:)(\))', \1\3.`

I'm not familiar with Ruby. Basically what you do is you have 3 groups, and from this three groups `( : and )` you get rid of the second one, the `:`.

I tested it in Notepad++ and it works.

I think this is called: regex backreference

Cheers.

Comment: That regex will only match the exact string `(:)`.  How exactly did you test it?  Anyway, Notepad++ is not a good tool for testing regexes.  There are lots of online regex testers like [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) out there.

Comment: as I said in the comment of his question. I gave him an example of how to remove a part from the whole regex expression. He could adapt his regex to fit it's needs. And for me Notepad++ is more than enough. Thanks for downvote anywayz.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I'm tempted.  I really don't think this a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume all parentheses will come in balanced pairs like they do in your example, this should be all you need:

```
"This is a (string :)".gsub!(/:(?=[^()]*\))/, '')
```

If the lookahead succeeds in finding a closing paren without seeing an opening paren first, the colon must be inside a `(...)` sequence.  Notice how I excluded the opening paren as well as the closing paren; that's essential.